# Firebase and admob unable to link

Tags: firebase, admob

I'm trying to link google admob and firebase.
And I'm using the instruction here https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6383165, and also checked some youtube vid, and they have button/options to link it to firebase on their admob page, unfortunately, ony my admob page, there isn't button/options link it to firebase.
There's is no firebase option on my admob page.
already created app on admob and and project on firebase console

Is there any reason for this or fix for this?

Comment: I am facing this same issue. No "Link to Firebase." option there. Did you get any solution for it? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't found any soulution yet. Will let you now if I did. Thanks